# make dynamic chart title name in excel template

Tags: excel

I prepared an excel template(with sheet, "Sheet1") having pie chart/bar chart. I was able to set up the chart title using

```
=Sheet1!$A$1
```

Now. I am using this template to create another excel files, with different sheetname, using JAVA APACHE POI. I am able to create charts, but as the sheetname is different in new excle file, the chart title doesnt show up in chart. it shows #REF.

How can i make it dynamic, I tried using INDIRECT but it says " function is invalid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [`CELL`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) function.

specifically, this formula will draw out the sheet name for any worksheet you place the formula in.

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

The formula `CELL("filename",A1)` returns the full path of the file, including the sheet name `C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\[myFile.xlsx]mySheetName`

The rest of the embedded formulas find the `]` in the file name and return the characters after it.

Comment: I tried, but I am getting same error "function invalid". It worked fine in an cell, but it give error when I use it in chart title

Comment: @user1631306 - ah ... now I see the problem. Yes, my solution won't work for that. I will see if I come up with another one.

Comment: if you are creating the other Excel files, can you always create a reference kind of sheet that will always have the same name, or does the title have to be based on the sheet name?

Comment: the cell reference always remain same, A1, only the sheet name gets changed.